# Creating Power set from a given vector<string> with error:"Vector subscript out of range"

Tags: c++, vector

I tried the following algorithm to find the power set from a given vector

```
std::vector<std::string> *NFAStates 
std::vector<std::string> *PowerSet
int state_lines = (*NFAStates).size()   
for (int i = 1; i < pow(2, state_lines); i++)
{


    for (int j = 0; j < state_lines; j++)
    {


        if (i &(1 << j) && !(*PowerSet)[i].empty())
        {

            (*PowerSet)[i].append("_");
            (*PowerSet)[i].append((*NFAStates)[j]);

        }
        else if (i &(1 << j) && (*PowerSet)[i].empty())
            (*PowerSet).push_back((*NFAStates)[j]);
    }
    std::cout << (*PowerSet)[i] << std::endl;
}
return 0;
```

i get an error "Vector subscript out of range"

Here *NFAStates consist of

```
S0
S1
S2
```

and *PowerSet is where my powerset elements are stored

it would be very helpful if i know why i am getting this error

Comment: Why on *earth* are you using pointers to vectors? And worse, *indeterminate* pointers at that.

Comment: You are de-referencing uninitialized pointers.

Comment: What is your `PowerSet->size()`?

Comment: @Paul  power set size is 2^state_lines

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @JayanthJamadagni *t would be very helpful if i know why i am getting this error* -- What in the error message isn't clear?  You are accessing an element out of bounds of the number of entries in the vector.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ i actually did, and it is breaking at if (i &(1 << j) && !(*PowerSet)[i].empty())

Comment: @JayanthJamadagni And what is `i` at that point? Does it fit within `(*PowerSet).size()`? Learn how to use the debugger correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code, with minimal mods, namely I changed pointers to references. I found no fault with it.

The problem lies elsewhere, probably in your initialization of the input vectors.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int func(std::vector<std::string>& NFAStates, std::vector<std::string> &PowerSet)
{
    int state_lines = NFAStates.size();
    //for (int i = 1; i < pow(2, state_lines); i++)
    for (int i = 1; i < (1 << state_lines); i++)  // this is more effective for powers of 2
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < state_lines; j++)
        {
            if (i &(1 << j) && !PowerSet[i].empty()) // <-- can't access [i] if PowerSet is empty.
            {
                PowerSet[i].append("_");
                PowerSet[i].append(NFAStates[j]);
            }
            else if (i &(1 << j) && PowerSet[i].empty())
                PowerSet.push_back(NFAStates[j]);
        }
        std::cout << PowerSet[i] << std::endl; // <-- can't access [i] if PowerSet is empty.
    }
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> NFAStates{ "S0", "S1", "S2" };
    std::vector<std::string> PowerSet{"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" };
    return func(NFAStates, PowerSet);
}
```

The program, notably, bugs when PowerSet is initially empty.

Maybe adding `PowerSet.resize(1 << NFAStates.size());` before the loop would fix your issue?